X and Y are random variables with X and Y ∼ Poi(λ) . Assuming X and Y are independent and that λ ≥ 100, show that P(|2X +Y −3λ| ≤ λ) ≥ 1/2.

X and Y are random variables with X and Y ∼ Poi(λ) . Assuming X and Y are independent and that λ ≥ 100, show that P(|2X +Y −3λ| ≤ λ) ≥ 1/2.


I let Z=2X+Y and so E(Z)=3( λ ) and V(Z)=5( λ ) and then substituted in Chebyshev and got a probability less than 5/( λ and as  λ  is greater than 100 this means (5/( λ ) is less than 5%.Not sure what to do next!Thanks for any help in advance.


Your notation is confusing.  I believe you mean "the probability that $(2X+Y-3\lambda)≤\lambda$ is $≥\frac 12$. "  Yes?  Assuming that, use the fact that $2x+Y$ is a Poisson process with mean $3\lambda$.
